# Production Flask-SocketIO + ZeroRPC

Tags: python, flask, wsgi, zerorpc

I've deployed a flask-socketio web server, but after installing zerorpc which installs gevent i'm facing a lot of troubles..
at first my code looked like this:

```
socketio.start_background_task(poll_events)
socketio.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", keyfile='key.pem', certfile='cert.pem')
```

I'm starting a background task which will constantly read from a queue and send messages through socketio. now that gevent is installed it flask-socketio will try to use it (which i'm fine with actually making my server a production server and not a development one) but then socketio.start_background_task blocks. So I read that

```
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()
```

is required.
So now my code looks like that:

```
socketio.start_background_task(poll_events)
WSGIServer(('0.0.0.0', 5000), app, keyfile='key.pem', certfile='cert.pem').serve_forever()
```

For some reason when debugging with pycharm I received a lot of weird greenlet exceptions and also I think that sometimes socketio messages are dropped so I decided to use eventlet. Then again, patching is required. So my code looks like this:

```
socketio.start_background_task(poll_events)
eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.wrap_ssl(eventlet.listen(("0.0.0.0", 5000)), keyfile='key.pem', certfile='cert.pem'), app)
```

Because of monkey patching zerorpc throws an exception
"gevent.exceptions.LoopExit: This operation would block forever"

What is the correct way to deploy a production server with flask + socketio + zerorpc?

Comment: Could this documentation helps perhaps: https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/server.html#gevent

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the issue, when debugging I choose "threading" as async_mode

```
 socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode="threading")
```

and when deploying with gunicorn I use gevent

```
CMD ["gunicorn", "-w", "1", "-k", "gevent","--reload", "web_app:app"]
```

For some reason gevent doesn't work without gunicorn and eventlet wouldn't work with zerorpc..